# Angles of vectors of same magnitude

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

$\vec{a} $ and $ \vec{b}$ are equal in magnitude. What is the angle between $(\vec{a} + \vec{b})$ and $(\vec{a} - \vec{b})$?

I'm aware it is $ 90$, but I don't know how to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\require{cancel}\;(\vec{a}+\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{a}-\vec{b}) = \vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}-\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{b}\cdot\vec{a}-\vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}= \cancel{|a|^2} - \bcancel{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}+\bcancel{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}}- \cancel{|b|^2}=\cdots\,$

Or, geometrically, think at a certain rhombus and recall that the diagonals are orthogonal.

Comment: Yes, I know it geometrically, but algebrically I can't quite understand how the 0 will help me automatically assume it's a 90 degrees angle. DD:

Comment: @Bunny-chan The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Definition) of two vectors is $0$ iff they are orthogonal, and the dot product of a vector with itself is the square of its magnitude. Those are basic enough properties of the dot product that they don't usually need proving. If you don't know, or can't use, those then you'll need to prove them starting from whatever definiton of the dot product you use.

Comment: Now it is clear to me. Thank you very much!